# Spring using Netbeans-Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name Netbeans

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am very much new to developing java applications using Spring framework. I have previously developed applications using MVC architecture but this Spring is really killing me.

I mean I can't a get a single new thing right in less than hour. Anyway, I am stuck in a very common problem while handling forms. I have tried for hours, searched the web for my problem and none of them have worked. Is it something to do with Netbeans? I don't know.

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form:form action="apptest.htm" commandName="userForm" method="POST">
            Name:<form:input path="name" />
            <br>
            Age:<form:input path="age" />
            <br>
            City:<form:input path="city" />
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <br> 
        </form:form>

    </body>
</html>
```

InsertController.java

```
package SpringApp.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;  
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import SpringApp.DAO.PeopleDAO;
import SpringApp.DAO.People;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/apptest.htm")
/**
 *
 * @author ROHAN
 */
public class InsertController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewRegistration(Map<String, Object> model) {
        People userForm = new People();    
        model.put("userForm", userForm); 
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    /*public String insertion(ModelMap modelMap) {
        ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");        
        PeopleDAO dao=(PeopleDAO)ctx.getBean("people");  
        int status=dao.saveEmployee(new People("Kitty",22,"khardah"));  
        modelMap.put("msg2","success");        
        return "test";
    }*/
    public String processRegistration(@ModelAttribute(value="userForm") People people,
            Map<String, Object> model) {
       model.put("name",people.getName());  
       model.put("city",people.getCity());
        return "test";
    }
}
```

People.java (Bean class)

```
package SpringApp.DAO;

public class People {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String city;

    public People()
    {
        super();
    }

    public People(String name,int age,String city)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
        this.city=city;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [name=" + name + ", age=" + age+ ", city=" + city + "]";
    }
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="SpringApp" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

index.jsp is my welcome page as configured in web.xml. Whenever I run the project, I get the following message:

```
29-Feb-2016 02:46:14.550 SEVERE [http-nio-8035-exec-183] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/SpringApp] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 17

14:     </head>
15:     <body>
16:         <form:form action="apptest.htm" commandName="userForm" method="POST">
17:             Name:<form:input path="name" />
18:             <br>
19:             Age:<form:input path="age" />
20:             <br>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userForm' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(index_jsp.java:228)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(index_jsp.java:180)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:134)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My project structure is as follows:

```
Web pages
   META-INF
   WEB-INF
      jsp
         test.jsp
      dispatcher-servlet.xml
      applicationContext.xml
      web.xml
   index.jsp(outside WEB-INF)
Source Packages
   Beans.xml
   SpringApp.Controllers
      InsertController
   SpringApp.DAO
      People.java
      PeopleDAO.java
```

test.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        Name: ${userForm.name} <br>
        City: ${userForm.city}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463883/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name)

Comment: I have tried everything that I have found here but to no avail. I feel it has something to do with netbeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userForm' available as request attribute

As you can see from stacktrace `index.jsp` can't map model attribute to form parameters.

This happans because you have `index.jsp` in your `<welcome-file-list>`. So `index.jsp` is loaded before controller and don't have access to model values.

To solve this problem you have to:

- move your `index.jsp` file to `WEB-INF/jsp` folder;
- change `<welcome-file-list>` to this:

  ```
  <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file></welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  ```

  or delete this tag at all.
- add `"/"` to `@RequestMapping` in `InsertController` class.

So, now your controller will process request, add value to model and pass it to `index.jsp`.

Below I posted full code.

**InsertController**

```
import SpringApp.DAO.People;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import java.util.Map;
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/", "/apptest.htm"})
/**
 *
 * @author ROHAN
 */
public class InsertController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewRegistration(Map<String, Object> model) {
        People userForm = new People();
        model.put("userForm", userForm);
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processRegistration(@ModelAttribute(value="userForm") People people,
                                      Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("name",people.getName());
        model.put("city",people.getCity());
        return "test";
    }
}
```

---

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Spring MVC</display-name>
  <description>Spring MVC</description>

  <!-- For web context -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      WEB-INF/application-context.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!--<welcome-file-list>-->
    <!--<welcome-file></welcome-file>-->
  <!--</welcome-file-list>-->
</web-app>
```

Comment: you sir have just made my day!!! I have one question, assuming I do not have any index file at all, rather it's equivalent is "demo.jsp". Then when I run the project, which file will open? Just a thought Sir.
Thanks :)

Comment: It depends on what view you return form your controller

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your `model attribute` is not bind with `request`, make below change in your `index.jsp`

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form:form action="apptest.htm" modelAttribute="userForm" method="POST">
                Name:<form:input path="name" />
                <br>
                Age:<form:input path="age" />
                <br>
                City:<form:input path="city" />
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <br> 
            </form:form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Now be sure that you have a `test.jsp` having `modelAttribute` of `People` `bean` otherwise it will again cause of error.

Comment: I made the change you asked for yet the problem persists. I have added the code for test.jsp in my question for your reference.